# Jalopy 1.9.4 and Eclipse (Indigo)

Tags: eclipse, jalopy

I have Jalopy 1.9.4 installed for eclipse (Indigo), jdk 1.5.

None of the options under jalopy's 'Java - Code generation' have been selected. This doesn't make any difference to jalopy. It inserts, for example, '@override' for methods and 'final' for variables wherever it sees necessary. I am not allowed to delete these inserted options. When I delete and save, they re-appear.

Any idea what's going wrong ?

thanks,
Soumya

Comment: Are you sure that the elements are actually inserted by Jalopy? Have you checked your Eclipse code cleanup settings or any other plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you positive that it is indeed Jalopy that inserts the elements? Maybe check your Eclipse code cleanup settings. Or uninstall Jalopy to make sure.

Do you use a single Jalopy profile? Or are there several profiles available? Maybe Jalopy is switching profiles on-the-fly and in one profile the code cleanup settings are different from those you expect. And make sure that no project specific settings are enabled.

Comment: It was indeed inserted by the Eclipse - Code Style and not by Jalopy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that Jalopy is configured to synchronise with a shared code convention? Check the settings below Eclipse->Jalopy->Synchronize

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but, there is nothing specified under synchronize either.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not allowed to remove the inserted elements? If your company wants them to be inserted and configured Jalopy accordingly, there is not much point to try and override company policies.

Comment: This is what I don't understand. We have imported the company code convention XML file. It has, for example, no mention of wanting to add '@override', but if I delete the jalopy inserted '@override' tags and save the file, the tags appear again. This, apparently is not effected by the checkbox selections made by editing jalopy settings from eclipse.